# Rest content manager API configuration

Tags: restfulapi, sites-10

After generating the access token in postman I am trying to list the publications using below Url

https://hostname/api/v2.0/publications

But I am getting below error in postman

"message" : "access denied for the user client-id#"
"data":{
"errorCode": "AccessDenied",
"category" : "security"
}

I am referring "Tridion Sites Content Manager  API client(admin)" service account and client id to generate the token.

But I am not sure about this error. can you please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the issue. we disabled the automatic user creation because of that I was getting "access denied" error.

Comment: Good find. I've heard of organizations intentionally disabling user creation. If that were an issue I'd recommend connecting user access to specific claims coming from the Identity Provider, but that's a bit off topic for your original question. :-D